# Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$ with symmetry $f(x)=f(\pi-x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

> Let $f(x) =\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx))$ and $f(x) = f(\pi-x)$. Considering this symmetry, prove that the Fourier coefficients satisfy $a_{2m+1}= b_{2m}= 0$.

My attempt so far:

Considering the form of the Fourier series of $f(x)$, the period is $2\pi$. Thus, we can write:
$$
a_{n} = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{x_0}^{x_0+2\pi} f(x) \cos({n x}) \,dx \\
= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \cos({n x}) \,dx \\
=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{0} f(x) \cos({n x}) \,dx + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \cos({n x}) \,dx
$$
Now working with just the first integral and making the substitution $x=\pi - t$
$$
I_1=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{t = 2\pi}^{\pi} f(\pi-t) \cos({n (\pi-t)}) \,(-dt) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(t) [\cos(n\pi)\cos(nt)-\sin(n\pi)\sin(nt)] \,dt \\
=\frac{1}{\pi} (-1)^n\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(t) \cos(nt) \,dt
$$
But I'm sure where to go from here/if this works. I was expecting to get something of the form:
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} (1+(-1)^n)\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(x) \cos(nx) \,dx
$$
To then show that only $a_{2m}$ are non-zero etc. but I can't seem to make the bounds work to do this. Is the along the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to split up the integral like that, you may want to leave the formula as
$$\begin{align*}a_n &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x_0}^{x_0 +2\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx + \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x_0+\pi}^{x_0+2\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx \\ &:= I_1 + I_2.\end{align*}$$

Then as you've done, we can pick the first integral and write $$\begin{align*}I_1 &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\pi-x_0}^{-x_0}f(\pi-t)\cos(n(\pi-t))\,(-dt) \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi}(-1)^n\int_{-x_0}^{\pi-x_0}f(t)\cos(nt)\,dt\end{align*}$$

Then compare the limits on both integrals.  They both have length $\pi$, so for them to be equal, we'd need the lower limits to equal:
$$-x_0 = x_0 + \pi \implies x_0 = -\pi/2.$$

That is, by setting $x_0=-\pi/2$ originally, we have $$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}((-1)^n+1)\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx$$
which is the form you were looking for.

---

That said, we don't actually need to split the integral in two, and by using the whole integral, we don't need to care about which $x_0$ we choose.  Using the same substitution but with the whole integral, we'd have
$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx = \frac{1}{\pi}(-1)^n\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx = (-1)^na_n \\ \implies \\(1 - (-1)^n)a_n = 0$$
which gives $2a_{2m+1} = 0.$